# Catia V5 VBA: Get partnumber in selected part

Tags: vba, properties, catia

I want to create a macro get properties of part & product in my design. I need to get partnumber of part.
When i selected in Tree or selected with "Product selection". It works with the same code:

```
 Dim objSel
 Set objSel = Catia.ActiveDocument.Selection
 parNo= objSel.Item(1).Value.PartNumber
```

But it's not convenient.
I want to get PartNumber when I select any object (Edge, plane, surface...). By all the way, how can I get it?

Thanks & Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

If you are selecting in an assembly you can use `Leafproduct` instead of `Value`

```vb
parNo = objSel.Item(1).LeafProduct.PartNumber
```

Comment: Wonderful, it works . I have been looking for this for a long time. Thank you so much.